# Convert Python dict to csr matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I'm using the function below to convert a dictionary of the form (row, col):value to a csr matrix. row and col are int, and value is float.

```
def convert(term_dict):
    # Create the appropriate format for the COO format.
    data = []
    row = []
    col = []
    for k, v in term_dict.items():
        r = int(k[0][1:])
        c = int(k[1][1:])
        data.append(v)
        row.append(r-1)
        col.append(c-1)
    # Create the COO-matrix
    coo = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)))
    # Let Scipy convert COO to CSR format and return
    return csr_matrix(coo)
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335059/converting-python-sparse-matrix-dict-to-scipy-sparse-matrix). I'm getting

> r = int(k[0][1:]) TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute
>   '**getitem**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really not shure what you are trying here:

```
for k, v in term_dict.items():
        r = int(k[0][1:])
        c = int(k[1][1:])
```

if you have a dict, like say

```
d = dict()
d[(1,2)] = 2.3232
d[(2,2)] = 12.3232

for k, v in d.items():
  #here k is (1,2)
  #k[0] == 1
  #k[0][1:] == 1[1:]
```

you are trying to slice something from an int type. What is your expected result?

try

```
for k, v in term_dict.items():
        r = int(k[0])
        c = int(k[1])
```

instead